# Expression about searches

Tags: idioms

I need to tell about a search process that returns a certain number of results from the most recent ones. In this case, which of the following sounds natural or idiomatic? Or any other alternative?

*(1) It will retrieve the most recent entries up to the entered number.*

*(2) It will retrieve as many entries as the entered number from the most recent ones.*

Comment: You seem to hope to compare "a certain number of results from the most recent ones" to "the most recent entries up to the entered number" or
"as many entries as the entered number from the most recent ones"; no?

Because those comparisons can't work, your Question can't be answered.

This is about logic and arithmetic, not English. Your example makes it clear you're unsure how to express this in whatever programming language you use, or your native tongue.

Could you first clarify this in either of them, then Post a new Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither sounds particularly right or wrong. To describe just what is being done you might take a bit from each.

It will retrieve as many entries as the number entered.

Comment: Please can you take the time to flesh out your answer with a reason why this is better.